# How can i improve my cron command so that the necessary folders are deleted?

Tags: cron, cpanel

I have a cron job input as shown.

As is, it does delete most of the files from 13 days ago or older, but it does not always get them all, and it frequently runs in to non-empty folders that it cannot delete (and reports as such). The error is: "find: cannot delete '[truncated]': Directory not empty"

it took weeks of trial and error to get to where i am now, and i need some direction on how to improve this from here. it seems that the way i have to enter cron commands into my cpanel to get them to work, does not always align with prescribed solutions given for cron commands - hence the weeks of trial and error.

```
find /home/account/mysite.com/subfolder/iamworkingin/ -mindepth 1 -mtime +13 -delete
```

I need everything prior to 13 days before the current date to be erased entirely beyond the listed working folder, erasing all subfolders in multiple/varied levels of depth.

Answer (score 0):

You could try increasing your `-mindepth` to 2 or more.

Or you could try `-exec`. That way you could force deletion using `rm -f` and/or `rm -r` for directories/recursive.

`find /home/account/mysite.com/subfolder/iamworkingin/ -mindepth 2 -mtime +13 -exec rm -fr {} \;`

Comment: The depth of subfolders can vary, sometimes being 5 or so deep. so should i remove `-mindepth` and instead make use of `-exec`? Your suggestion said `rm -f` yet your example uses `rm -r`. Which should i use here? Does use of `-exec` require use of `{}`? As my cPanel GUI doesn't have me enter the close-line of `\;`.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I've edited to clarify the use of `-f` and `-r`. Though forget that then if your cPanel doesn't allow `-exec` anyway. So perhaps it'd be better to increase `mindepth` to 5 or more with what you have first and see if that helps things.